# .NET Go back with refresh

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, .net, mvc

Hola estoy trabajando con una aplicacion en .NET y para los botones que van atras tengo implementada esta función:

```
function GoBackWithRefresh(event) {
            if ('referrer' in document) {
                //window.location = document.referrer;
                /* OR */
                location.replace(document.referrer);
            } else {
                //window.history.go(-1); //.back();
                window.history.back();
            }
        }
```

pero al haber más de 2 pantallas entra en bucle el botón atrás es decir:
tengo el index, pantalla 1 y la pantalla 2, si le das al boton de atras desde la pantalla 1 al index funciona, una vez entras en la pantalla 2 y le das al botón atrás funciona bien pero si le das otra vez al boton de atras entra en bucle entre la pantalla 1 y 2.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta.